# How to use YouTube Data API v3 to start the default 'Go Live' stream

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

Selecting 'go live' from the camera icon in YouTube, brings me to the studio where my default stream is.

I seem to need to navigate there (to enable it) before I can start uploading data via rtmp to that stream. Similarly, if there is a break in the stream for a minute or so, the stream automatically ends, and i need to go to the page and click the 'dismiss' button to start it again.

I found I can programmatically check if the stream is running with:

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXX_AUTHTOKEN" "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveStreams?part=snippet,cdn,contentDetails,status&mine=true"`

where I get the an entry in the JSON with the same `dn.ingestionInfo.streamName` as the stream key on the studio page. The entry also shows `contentDetails.isReusable=true` and `status.streamStatus=active` (where I believe it needs to be 'ready' to be able to accept / start the stream.

```json
    {
      "kind": "youtube#liveStream",
        "title": "Default stream key",
        "description": "Description for default stream key",
        "isDefaultStream": false
      },
      "cdn": {
        "ingestionType": "rtmp",
        "ingestionInfo": {
          "streamName": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
          "ingestionAddress": "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2",
          "backupIngestionAddress": "rtmp://b.rtmp.youtube.com/live2?backup=1",
          "rtmpsIngestionAddress": "rtmps://a.rtmps.youtube.com/live2",
          "rtmpsBackupIngestionAddress": "rtmps://b.rtmps.youtube.com/live2?backup=1"
        },
        "resolution": "variable",
        "frameRate": "variable"
      },
      "status": {
        "streamStatus": "active",
        "healthStatus": {
          "status": "good"
        }
      },
        "isReusable": true
      }
    }
```

Is there an API set I can use to reuse this default stream and programmatically change its state from active to ready?

I tried doing this below, but it always gives a new `streamName` instead of changing the `status.streamStatus` of the default one.

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer AUTHTOKEN" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{'id':'STREAMID_FROM_DEFAULT_IN_STATUS_CALL','snippet':{'title':'test','description':'test.'},'status':{'streamStatus':'ready'},'cdn':{'ingestionType':'rtmp','frameRate':'variable','resolution':'variable','ingestionInfo':{'streamName':'STREAM_NAME_FROM_DEFAULT_IN_STATUS_CALL'}}}" --request POST "https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveStreams?part=snippet,status,cdn"`.

However, this returns a different `id`, and a different `cdn.ingestionInfo.streamName` than the ones I specified in the call.

Thoughts or ideas on how I can reuse the default 'Go live' studio stream programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

There's the [`LiveBroadcasts.transition`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/transition) API endpoint, that allows to change the status of your already created broadcast.

Issue the following `curl` command (exemplified below in `bash`'s syntax), for to change the status of the broadcast identified by `$BROADCAST_ID` to `live`:

```
$ curl \
--request POST \
--header "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts/transition?part=id,snippet,contentDetails,status&broadcastStatus=live&id=$BROADCAST_ID"
```

As per the official specification:

> [**`broadcastStatus`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/transition#broadcastStatus)  (string)
>
> The `broadcastStatus` parameter identifies the state to which the broadcast is changing. Note that to transition a broadcast to either the `testing` or `live` state, the `status.streamStatus` must be `active` for the stream that the broadcast is bound to.
> [...]

prior to call this endpoint, you'll have to have your stream be `active` already.

Also, depending of the way you interact programmatically with your broadcast, you may well need have your broadcast set to automatic restart, via the respective broadcast property [`enableAutoStart`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#contentDetails.enableAutoStart).

Comment: I tried this, and it doesn't seem to work. I started with a stream that is active, created a broadcast with enableAutoStart=true, called bind to add the stream to the broadcast. verified the broadcast had the active streamId, and it had lifeCycleStatus=ready. (enableAutoStart I guess only works if the stream transitions and is not already running?) I then attempted to transition broadcastStatus=live with the call you suggested, though get a 403 -->  Invalid Transition.

Comment: Have you first transitioned to `testing` and, after `lifeCycleStatus` became `testing`, transition to `live`? There's an official document that implies this sequence of events: [Life of a Broadcast](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/life-of-a-broadcast).

Comment: Yes I tried the call to move it to testing, which gave the same 403 error. curl --request POST H "Authorization: Bearer XXXX" "https://www.googlea
pis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts/transition?part=id,snippet,contentDetails,status&broadcastStatus=testing&id=z--Lm8b1mU0"
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Invalid transition",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid transition",
        "domain": "youtube.liveBroadcast",
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: I added more details on the problem in this question, since it's hard to fit it in a comment here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67592373/youtubedata-api-v3-transition-of-ready-to-live-broadcast-fails-with-an-acti